# Best environment practice when working with Queues in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-sqs

I have an application which uses queues in order to send emails.

In a production environment, should I run the queue:listen command in the same application server where the application resides?  Or should I do outsorcing?

So far,I've been in a dev environment working with two command lines, one for the php artisan serve command in order to get the application running and the other for the php artisan queue:listen command. If outsorcing is better for production environment, would I have to modify my code so I can work with Beanstalkd, Amazon SQS or another?

Comment: You can't outsource the queue *listening*, just the queue itself. The listener needs to be run on your servers (but you could conceivably have a web server and a separate one dedicated to queue processing).

Comment: To build on @ceejayoz's comment, if you choose any of the work queue service for which Laravel has drivers included, you won't need to make any changes to your existing code, because the Queue contracts force a consistent API. Aside from that, if you're looking for details on how to setup queues on your server, the [Laravel Queues Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queues) explains that in a pretty good way, even including help on how to user a process monitor such as [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org) to make sure the listener is always up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Reference Link :: 
http://laravelcoding.com/blog/laravel-5-beauty-sending-mail-and-using-queues#14-about-queues

Helped me with my approach for sending notification message to gcm and to the registered mobiles.